# Import problems python/pyqt

Tags: python, pycharm

Ive got some import problems in python. When I want to import the PyQt5 library I just get the error "No module named 'PyQt5'". The folder is in the path C:\Python\Python37\Lib\PyQt5. I can import tkinter and the folder is in the same path as PyQt5

Code: from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
Error:ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5'

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please post your error as text and not image.

Comment: How did you install the modules? Are you using a virtual environment?

Comment: Im using the environment from pycharm which was created at the start.

Comment: I converted a UI file from the QT Designer to a .py which is in the path C:\Python\Python37\Lib\PyQt5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using a virtual environment, the modules available in a normal machine can't be imported unless you grant permission.

1. if you are using pycharm, every project is a virtual wrapper. so do install again or change interpreter preference in pycharm (if you installed locally).
2. Do install again through:
   1. terminal: Type
   pip install PyQt5
   2. if you are using pycharm, install from the interpreter preferences.

Comment: Now I can find the folder but I now just get the error: ImportError: DLL load failed